# Is this just a coincidence that 0xaaaaaaaa represents binary with even positions set as 1

Tags: binary, hex

Is this just a coincidence that hexadecimal 0xaaaaaaaa represents binary with even positions set as 1.

Similarly something as elegant as 0x55555555 represents binary with odd positions set as 1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binary representation of 5 is 0101. So 0X55555555 has 16 ones, 16 zeros and the ones,zeros take alternate positions. Similarly 0X33333333 has 16 ones, 16 zeros and 2 consecutive ones, 2 consecutive zeros alternate.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing special about those numbers per se, other than the fact that their corresponding bit patterns are useful.

I think the key realization here is that it's super easy to come up with a compact hex number to represent any longer bit pattern (even easier if it's repeating), right off the top of your head.

Why? Because it's trivial to convert from hex-to-binary or binary-to-hex - every four bits of the pattern can be neatly represented by one hex digit:

[image]

So let's say I wanted this 16-bit mask: `1110111011101110`. This is `1110` repeated 4 times, so it's just some hex digit, 4 times.  Since `1110` is 14 in decimal, that's gonna be "E", so our mask would be: `0xEEEE`.